# How to make video fill frame using AVFoundation

Tags: swift, avfoundation

Beginner at Swift. My video does not fill it's frame. Here is my code. What do I need to implement for it to take up it's space that I set up in Storyboard?

import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellview", for: indexPath) as! DataCellClass

    let videourl = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sample", ofType: "mp4")!)

    let avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: videourl as URL)

    cell.PlayerView?.playerLayer.player = avPlayer

    cell.PlayerView.player?.play()

    return cell
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at Content Mode for the AVPlayer within your DataCellClass in Storyboard. Make sure it is set to Aspect Fill

This may help. https://useyourloaf.com/blog/stretching-redrawing-and-positioning-with-contentmode/